# if with ScrollTo in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, scrollto

Sorry for the newbie question, but I'm trying to implement a scrollview with a logical text based on a preference value relating to an .id passed to the view.  The code is something like this, but I keep getting a Type () cannot conform to 'View' error:

```
ScrollViewReader {proxy in
                
                ScrollView (.vertical) {
                    
                    if (preferences.scrollPosition != 0) {
                        withAnimation {
                            proxy.scrollTo(preferences.scrollPosition)
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Because `withAnimation` is not a `View`. What do you want to display in the `ScrollView`? It doesn't make sense to call an animation in a view body like this

Comment: Thanks. I want to scollto the .id point. Taking out withanimation returns the same error. The code with animation works within a button closure for example.

Comment: This works for example at the end of the ScrollViewReader:

 Button("Scroll to Top") {
                            withAnimation {
                                proxy.scrollTo(1)
                            }

Comment: It’s the same error because none of the functions are giving you a `View` type. In SwiftUI, you describe the content as `View`s in the `body`. So for example, you may want `Text("Hello!")` in there instead. The animation should happen on a button click, on the view appearing etc, up to you

Comment: I see what you're saying.  Any ideas for a workaround that doesn't add text?  Maybe some empty view return?

Comment: But then what content are you scrolling to need the `ScrollView` for? I think you need to add more code to your question like what views you are scrolling and when you want to run the scroll to function

Comment: Essentially I'm putting the scrollto buttons in a pullout side menu, then calling the view in the main view with a scrollto based on the preferences state set in the side menu.

Comment: Without a bit more code of the view it's hard to fix. Basically just make sure you only have views in the `ScrollView`, and you call the scroll function whenever some action happens (such as clicking the button in the side menu)

Comment: I figure it out.  You can add .onChange in the scrollview relating to the preferences state and that will run the scrollto.  Thanks for the input though!

Answer (score 0):

Updating my post: I was incorrect with the ordering

I'm just trying to put together a more concrete example for reference, is this similar to what you want/have?

```
import SwiftUI

class Preferences: ObservableObject {
  @Published var scrollPosition: UnitPoint = .center
}

struct TestView: View {
  
  @StateObject var preferences = Preferences()
  
  var body: some View {
    ScrollViewReader {proxy in
      ScrollView (.vertical) {

      }
      .onAppear(perform: {
        if (preferences.scrollPosition != .zero) {
            withAnimation {
              proxy.scrollTo(preferences.scrollPosition)
            }
          }
      })
    }
  }
}

struct TestView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  
  static var previews: some View {
    TestView()
  }
}
```

Comment: Apple's Developer page has it the other way around:https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/scrollviewreader